# Retaining conditional color after compose() into new cells with flextable

Tags: r, flextable

I'm trying to build a multiline cell with conditionally colored values.

I can color them in their individual cells, but when I then compose them into a multiline cell they loose their formatting, even if I compose(as_paragraph(as_chunk())) them first:

[image]

The code I'm using is:

```
  color(i = ~ Case1_p < .2, 
        j = ~ Case1_p, 
        color = "red"
        ) %>%
  flextable::compose( j = "Case1_p",
                      value = as_paragraph( as_chunk(Case1_p) )
                      ) %>%
  
  flextable::compose( j = "fp", 
                    value = as_paragraph("fre=", as_chunk(Case1_f), 
                                         "\n",
                                         "pos=", as_chunk(Case1_p)
                                         )
                    ) %>%
```

I'm not adverse to building the multiline cell in a different way either, as doing it like this breaks autofit(), but the only other way I can think of doing it is to build a dataframe with lines and columns, and that just seems super hokey.

Total WIP for David:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("flextable")
library(officer)
library(glue)
 

dt = tribble(
  ~Type, ~Image,     ~Days, ~Case1_f, ~Case1_p, ~Case1_m, ~Case1_sd, ~Case2_x,
  "1-6",  "test.png", 1,    0.012345, 0.14,    0.54,     1.06, "1<br>2",
  "1-6",  "test.png", 2,    0.01,     0.74,    0.54,     1.06, "1\n2",
  "1-6",  "test.png", 3,    0.01,     0.74,    0.54,     1.06, "1\n2",
  "1-6",  "test.png", 4,    0.01,     0.74,    0.54,     1.06, "1\n2",
  "6-1",  "test.png", 1,    0.01,     0.74,    0.54,     1.06, "1\n2",
  "6-1",  "test.png", 2,    0.01,     0.14,    0.54,     1.06, "1\n2"
)


fontName = "Arial"
fontSize = 8

set_flextable_defaults( font.family = fontName, 
                        font.size = fontSize,
                        font.color = "black",
                        digits = 2, 
                        decimal.mark = ".", 
                        big.mark = " ", 
                        na_str = "na", 
                        fmt_date = "%d/%m/%Y"
                        )

width_type  <- gdtools::m_str_extents("Type",         fontname = fontName, fontsize = fontSize)[1,1]/72
width_days  <- gdtools::m_str_extents("Days",         fontname = fontName, fontsize = fontSize)[1,1]/72
width_fp    <- gdtools::m_str_extents("Frequency",    fontname = fontName, fontsize = fontSize)[1,1]/72
width_mmp   <- gdtools::m_str_extents("Median (iqr)", fontname = fontName, fontsize = fontSize)[1,1]/72
width_sp    <- gdtools::m_str_extents(" ",             fontname = fontName, fontsize = fontSize)[1,1]/72

blanks = c("blank1", "blank2")


flextable(dt,
          col_keys = c("Type", "Days", "blank1", "fp", "mmp", "Case1_f", "Case1_p", "Case1_m", "Case1_sd", "blank2", "Case2_x")
          ) %>%
  set_header_labels( fp = "Frequency\nPositivity",
                     mmp = "Mean_(sd)\nMedian_(iqr)\nP-value"
                 ) %>%
  add_header_row( values = c("", "", "Case 1", "", "Case 2"),
                  colwidths = c(2, 1, 6, 1, 1)
                  ) %>%
  width( j = ~Type, width = width_type ) %>%
  width( j = ~Days, width = width_days ) %>%
  width( j = ~fp,   width = width_fp ) %>%
  width( j = ~mmp,  width = width_mmp ) %>%
  width( j = ~blank1+blank2,  width = width_sp ) %>%
  #
  color(i = ~ Case1_p < .2, 
        j = ~ Case1_p, 
        color = "red"
        ) %>%
  set_formatter( Case1_f = function(x) sprintf( "%.1f%%", x*100 ) ) %>%
  flextable::compose( j = "Case1_p",
                      value = as_paragraph( as_chunk(Case1_p) )
                      ) %>%
  
  flextable::compose( j = "fp", 
                    value = as_paragraph(as_chunk(Case1_f), 
                                         "\n",
                                         as_chunk( Case1_p, 
                                                   #props = fp_text(color = "green"),
                                                   formatter=function(x) sprintf("%.1f%%", x*100) 
                                                   )
                                         )
                    ) %>% 
    flextable::compose( j = "mmp",
                    value = as_paragraph(as_chunk(Case1_m), " ", as_bracket(Case1_sd),
                                         "\n",
                                         as_chunk(Case1_m), " ", as_bracket(Case1_sd),
                                         "\n",
                                         "***", " ", as_bracket(Case1_m)
                                         )
                    ) %>%
  merge_v(j = "Type") %>%
  valign(valign = "top") %>% 

  theme_booktabs() %>%
  # empty_blanks() %>% 
  # fix_border_issues()
  # autofit()
  border( j=blanks, border.top = shortcuts$b_null(), border.bottom = shortcuts$b_null(), part = "all") %>%
  bg( j=blanks, bg = "transparent", part = "all") %>%
  void( j=blanks, part = "all")
```

Comment: I think you need to use `props` argument of `as_chunk`, i.e. `"pos=", as_chunk(Case1_p, props = fp_text_lite(color = "red"))`. call to `as_chunk(var)` refers to value of `var` (and not its formatted value) but you can associate it with a chunk format (arg `props`).

Comment: Many thanks @DavidGohel.  I think the final part of your reply says that there's a way to extract the properties of the referenced cell and copy them into the new chunk, yes?  I'm afraid I can't find it.  Could you give me a pointer please?

Comment: not really, could you share a reproducible example so that I can start from where you are?

Comment: @DavidGohel  For sure.  My wip appended.  The only way I can see of doing it at the moment is to add a formatting routine for each chunk I wish to decorate and not use the color() and set_formatter() functions.

Comment: @DavidGohel  (Also does empty_blanks() work the way you intend?  It seems to empty those columns that are blank in the original data frame rather than those that are blank in the output.  I've pulled out the contents of the function to use them directly in this case.

Comment: OK, saw your code but I'd like to focus on a minimal example. So what you want to do is to have 'freq' line in black and 'pos' line in red when  Case1_p < .2. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @DavidGohel That's the test example, correct.  The more general question though is can I use, for example, your color()/bg()/... selectors to decorate the cells I need, and then just copy those cells into the multiline paragraph complete with their decorations and formatting, or do I need to abandon that and decorate the cell via a function call in as_paragraph() (which I think is easy enough to do (unless I've missed something), it just breaks some of the nice ethos you've created in flextable and feels a bit hacky)?

Comment: OK, I am sorry, I thought you could NOT do something. Then your code already do it (you can use fp_text_lite instead of fp_text). Answers to your questions: no, not possible ; no, use mk_par ; empty_blak works the way I intend ; no you can't, yes you need to use compose/mk_par if any multi-content.